# Default value for div menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, default-value

I have a problem with the div menu.

I would like to have that the value for the data-link variable is set to first so that when I initially load the page, there is below the menu the line ffffffffffff. As the code is now, the line would be empty.

Then, if I click another item on the menu, the content of the new menu item overwrites the previous content.

```
<div id="menu_about">
    <a class="link" href="#about" data-link="first">
        &nbsp;&nbsp; Why We Exist
    </a> &#8226; 
    <a class="link" href="#about" data-link="second">Who We Are</a> &#8226;
    <a class="link" href="#about" data-link="third">What We Do</a> &#8226; 
    <a class="link" href="#about" data-link="fourth">How We Think</a> &#8226; 
    <a class="link" href="#about" data-link="fifth">Where We Are Going</a>
</div>
<div id="pages_about" class="textContainer_about">
    <div class="textWord_about" data-link="first">
        <p>ffffffffffff</p>
    </div>
    <div class="textWord_about" data-link="second">
        <p>ffffffffffffffffff</p>
    </div>
    <div class="textWord_about" data-link="third">
        <p>ffffffffffffffffffff</p>
    </div>
    <div class="textWord_about" data-link="fourth">
        <p>ffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</p>
        <p>ffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</p>
        <p>ffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</p>
        <p>ffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</p>
        <p>ffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</p>
    </div>
    <div class="textWord_about" data-link="fifth">
        <p>fffffffffffffffffffffffffff</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$('.textWord_about').hide();

$('.link').click(function() {
    $('.textWord_about').hide();       
    $('.textWord_about[data-link=' + $(this).data('link') + ']').fadeIn({
        width: '200px'
    }, 300);
});
```

Comment: Is that double `<head>` tag on purpose or to show something in particular?

Comment: Might want to include relevant CSS or set up a jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to hide them seperatly or do like I did 
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Komlan/4wyjA/)
I display the element you wanted to show with show() like this

```
   $('.textWord_about[data-link="first"]').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Select all but the first `.textWord_about` when you initially hide them.

Use `:gt(0)`:

```
$('.textWord_about:gt(0)').hide();
```

[jsfiddle.net/mLfgW](http://jsfiddle.net/mLfgW/)

Or `.slice(1)`:

```
$('.textWord_about').slice(1).hide();
```

[jsfiddle.net/mLfgW/1](http://jsfiddle.net/mLfgW/1/)